# Why does Regex Include the space in its Match

Tags: javascript, regex, match, space

I am trying to match (once or twice) any instance of fixed|local|scroll
But I do not want to capture the trailing space. I thought I fixed this by putting in (?: ... \s*) but it is still capturing that trailing space.

For example:

Here is my regex:

```
((?:(?:fixed|local|scroll)\s*){1,2})
```

Here is the string:

```
background: url("my image.jpg") left right 2px 50% 75% repeat scroll border-box padding-box;
```

Here is the match:

```
`scroll `
```

Expected:

```
`scroll`
```

Btw I am using the following site to test my regex:

Comment: By twice, you mean consecutively, right? (Otherwise, your whole question would be a mess, and would not make sense.) When it matches twice, you have to have a space in between. Otherwise, the two occurrences would not be a single (sub)-string, and would not be capturable with a single regex.

Comment: Right. It would be consecutively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
\s*((?:\s*?\b(?:fixed|local|scroll)\b){1,2})
```

or

```
\s*((?:\s*?(?:fixed|local|scroll)){1,2})
```

*(if word boundaries are not needed)*

Explanation: since `\s*` is by default greedy, all leading white spaces are "eaten" before the catpure group.

Comment: I tried the same thing in my answer originally and then I realized it doesn't actually work for matching 2 words since the lazy modifier makes it stop.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason this makes it only match one word (even when there are two that should match).

Answer (score 2):

In the regex you gave, the outer-most group is the only capturing group and that contains the `\s*`.

You could try something like this which is a bit longer:

```
(fixed|scroll|local)(\s+(fixed|scroll|local))?
```

An occurrence of `(fixed|scroll|local)` followed by one more optional one. Duplicating it like that makes things easier because it allows you to say "whitespace is valid between matches but not after".

Another option would just be to deal with the trailing space programmatically using trim.

Comment: Your answer works, but it does not keep with the same formatting that I wanted. Thanks for your help though.